# AWS: concurrent queue system?

Tags: amazon-web-services

Ok So I have a few users wanting to perform a task at the same time.

The task is executed on a lambda and takes a few seconds.

I want to limit the number of parallels execution of the task to 3.

Meaning if 10 users call it at the same time, 3 tasks will run for 3 users, and the 7 remaining users will be put in a waiting queue.

When one user's task finish, before exiting, the task lookup in the waiting queue, extract another user from the queue, and launch a new task for this user (fire and forget), then exit.

I need to be sure that there is no execution duplicate, so I'm storing the queue on a small server (in lightsail) and in the RAM, but I'm not sure that would scale well.

Can I have a similar workflow in a serverless way? not sure using SQS can solve my issue

Comment: Define what exactly you need and how exactly SQS is insufficient. What does "only one item at a time" mean? How exactly are "20 items in parallel" supposed to behave?

Comment: @deceze , hey, sorry about that, I edited my question to explain in depth my issue!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you're asking for can be achieved with SQS and Lambda simply with this:

- subscribe the Lambda function to the SQS queue with a batch size of 1, so a function gets executed as soon as a message is in the queue and only one message is handled per invocation
- throttle that Lambda function to 3 concurrent invocations, so no more than 3 tasks are handled in parallel

Comment: Well, OP wants to be sure that there's no duplicate execution, so SQS is not the best solution here. FIFO Queue would fit here propably.